# how to select a menu item in menu bar using eggplant

Tags: eggplant

I recently started working on eggplant tool. In one of the screen I have Menu bars like File, View, help etc., Each menu bars contains menu items. some time I have to select the first menu item in menu bar and sometimes I have to select the other menu item in menu bar.
How to select a menu item in menu bar.

Could someone pls reply if anyone has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcuts or hotkeys on the menu items.

For example: to reach "About" menu item in the expamle.

```
typeText altKey&H
typeText A
```

[image: MenuBar]

If you don't have any hotkeys.
You can search for the image "Help" and click then use downArrow

```
WaitFor 10, "helpButtonImage"   
Click FoundImageLocation()    
typeText downArrow,downArrow,return
```

Answer (score -1):

We can do this by building search rectangle with a reference image